# My Powerlevel10k doesn't work right (I use omz)

Tags: terminal, themes, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

usually the powerlevel10k configurator asks you what style of powerlevel10k you want to run (lean classic etc.) when you press `p10k configure`. They didn't present me those options instead my they just asked me some other questions like if I wanted to display time and so on.
After that they defaulted my terminal to this:
[image]

Why doesn't it look like the usual powerlevel10k? And why doesn't it show me my icons even though I installed their `MesloLGS Nf`font

Answer (score 1):

From the Powerlevel10k [FAQ](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#some-prompt-styles-are-missing-from-the-configuration-wizard):

> #### Some prompt styles are missing from the configuration wizard
>
> [snip]
>
> If there is no UTF-8 locale on the system, configuration wizard won't offer prompt styles that use
> Unicode characters. *Fix*: Install a UTF-8 locale. Verify with `locale -a`.
>
> [snip]

Command `locale -a` lists all installed locales. If you run it, you'll notice that there is no UTF-8 locale. So you need to install one. How you do that depends on your OS. Google "Install locale on **your OS**".