# Tmux as Entrypoint deactivates unicode characters

Tags: docker, unicode, zsh, tmux

I'm building a Docker image including a ready to use terminal with all my usual tools.

I'm running a 2020 Macbook Air M1 running Monterey 12.5.1.

I'd like to start the container directly in a tmux session, but the characters display behavior is inconsistent.

- When `ENTRYPOINT` is `["zsh"]` and I execute `tmux` in the interactive container, the characters are as expected :
  [image: Conform characters]
  *and when executing `tmux` :*
  [image: conform tmux]
- but when changing the `ENTRYPOINT` to `["zsh", "-c", "tmux"]` :
  [image: not conform tmux]

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ARG USER=ben
ENV GROUP=${USER}
ENV HOME=/home/${USER}
ENV TMUX_SESSION_NAME=devops

RUN groupadd ${GROUP}

RUN useradd -m -g ${GROUP} ${USER}

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tzdata
RUN apt-get install -y \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    git \
    wget \
    docker \
    vim \
    fzf \
    zsh \
    fd-find \
    zsh-syntax-highlighting \
    tmux \
    locales \
    locales-all

RUN usermod -s /bin/zsh ${USER}

# Configuring locales
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris /etc/localtime \
    && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

USER ${USER}
WORKDIR /home/${USER}

# Oh-My-Zsh configuration
RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh -O - | zsh || true

# ZSH plugins
RUN git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-$HOME/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/themes/powerlevel10k
RUN git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.git ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-${HOME}/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting
RUN git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-${HOME}/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions

COPY --chown=${USER}:${GROUP} zshrc ${HOME}/.zshrc
COPY --chown=${USER}:${GROUP} tmux.conf ${HOME}/.tmux.conf
COPY --chown=${USER}:${GROUP} p10k.zsh ${HOME}/.p10k.zsh

# ENTRYPOINT ["zsh", "-c", "tmux"]
ENTRYPOINT ["zsh"]
```

Comment: Can you make clearer the difference between what you want and what you're getting? They look pretty similar

Comment: What does `locale` report in each situation? The symptoms look similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64849394).

Comment: Also something to try: `ENTRYPOINT ["zsh", "-i", "-c", "tmux"]`. I'm not at all familiar with these tools, but it could be that the `tmux` call needs to be explicitly set as an [interactive shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/551654/).

Comment: tmux may not known about your Mac terminal capabilities. Check TERM, and be sure that you have the data for that terminal on your remote computer (it is in one package). Or just select in your mac a more compatible terminal (e.g. `xterm`). And also locale. The root account may not support UTF-8 (which it is very good for non interactive commands, but possibly not ok for a shell)

Comment: @JoshFriedlander : the icons & special characters I have when entering the container and then manually starting tmux disappear when including tmux in the ENTRYPOINT statement.

Comment: @Gairfowl : both situations return :
`LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi : I couldn't find any difference in the TERM var between the two situations, although on the mac TERM=xterm-256color and in the docker containers (in both cases) TER=screen-256color. 

Anyways, I found another solution that I wrote down below. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the reason for this behavior, but I investigated starting `tmux` directly from `zsh` and not in the `ENTRYPOINT`, and the solution that solved my issue was to set the environment variables `ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true`.
Thank you all for your help !